# COMException "The package id is corrupted" while installing cortana voice commands

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, cortana

I'm trying to add cortana voice commands to my app. However the moment I try to install the voice command definitions I get the COMException "Die Paketidentität ist beschädigt" (The package id is corrupted).

I reduced voice command definition file to a minimum, but that had no effect. My code is:

```
private static async Task InstallVoiceCommandsIfNecessary()
{
#if WINDOWS_UWP
    var installed = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("VoiceCommandsInstalled");

    if (!installed)
    {
        try
        {
            var storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(
                                    new Uri("ms-appx:///Cortana/VoiceCommands.xml"));
            await Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.
                InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(storageFile);
            // The line above is throwing the exception ----^
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["VoiceCommandsInstalled"] = true;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
#endif
}
```

called from OnLaunched.

The VoiceCommands.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">

 <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="StopNowCommandSet_en-us">
    <AppName>Stopnow</AppName>
    <Example> stop a time </Example>

    <Command Name="stopWatch">
      <Example> stop a time  </Example>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> stop [a] time [in] </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Launching the stopwatch </Feedback>
      <Navigate/>
    </Command>

  </CommandSet>

</VoiceCommands>
```

I've put a breakpoint at the InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync and the GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync succeeded.

The problem seems to be the InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync call.

**Update:**

The same code works in the Windows 10 Mobile Emulator. Could this be local installation problem?

Comment: It is probably unhappy about the argument you pass to GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync().  Put a big red arrow at the statement that fails.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I missed this important information. It seems to be the InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync call. I updated the question.

Comment: This error more like an installing error to me. Can you try uninstall the app from your device and deploy your app again?